# picture_csp_enc.c:(.text+0x7d0): undefined reference to `SharpYuvInit'

Tags: gdal

I downloaded gdal by vcpkg and trying to compile gdal in Linux.

I am using next flags in cmake:
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DGDAL_USE_TIFF_INTERNAL=ON -DGDAL_USE_GEOTIFF_INTERNAL=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DBUILD_CSHARP_BINDINGS=ON -DSWIG_DIR=/home/swig/Lib -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=/home/swig/./swig.exe -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/vcpkg/buildtrees/gdal/install" -DFileGDB_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/FileGDB/include -DFileGDB_LIBRARY=/home/FileGDB/lib64/FileGDBAPI.lib -DOGR_ENABLE_DRIVER_FILEGDB_PLUGIN=ON -DGDAL_ENABLE_DRIVER_ECW_PLUGIN=ON -DECW_INCLUDE_DIR="/home/ERDAS ECW JPEG 2000 SDK 5.5.0/Desktop Read-Only/include" -DECW_LIBRARY="/home/ERDAS ECW JPEG 2000 SDK 5.5.0/Desktop Read-Only/lib/vc141/x64/NCSEcw.lib" -DGDAL_ENABLE_DRIVER_WEBP_PLUGIN=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" ../src/v3.7.2-727954cc71.clean

after make I see the next error:

usr/bin/ld:  ....... /libwebp.a(picture_csp_enc.c.o): in function `ImportYUVAFromRGBA': picture_csp_enc.c:(.text+0x7d0): undefined reference to` SharpYuvInit'
/usr/bin/ld: picture_csp_enc.c:(.text+0x7d7): undefined reference to `SharpYuvGetConversionMatrix' /usr/bin/ld: picture_csp_enc.c:(.text+0x823): undefined reference to` SharpYuvConvert'

Maybe I miss some flags ...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

I need compilation passing.